# Looking for a reference by Moree and Niklash

Tags: reference-request

A while ago I saved an internet reference to a work by P. Moree and G. Niklasch, published exclusively on a website, related to high-precision computations of constants related to prime numbers. I believe the paper was entitled

"*Ultraprecision number-theoretical constants*"

and was dated somewhere from 2002. The link I have no longer works:

http://www.gn-50uma.de/alula/essays/Moree/Moree.en.shtml

Searching on google unfortunately yields no relevant results either. I was wondering if anyone can provide a link to this paper or help find a journal where it might have been published.

Comment: Can you give more information about the paper? Is it a pdf, word, html?

Comment: Is this it? http://guests.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/moree/Moree.en.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The WaybackMachine has the page referenced saved here (from March 2018): http://web.archive.org/web/20180325095137/http://www.gn-50uma.de:80/alula/essays/Moree/Moree.en.shtml.

Comment: That's it, thank you! I did not know about the WaybackMachine, I will make sure to use it in the future.

Comment: @Klangen Nor did I until some years ago I saw a link on Terry Tao's webpage.